# Split an array by a character

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have this array similar to this:

```
var arr = ['Green','Red','Silver','|','blue','Yellow']
```

The array will always have the character `|` separating it, but will have random amount of values in the array.

I want to make all the values on both sides of the `|` into two seperate arrays.

For example, I would want the above codes output to be:

```
['Green','Red','Silver']
['blue','Yellow']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var arr = ['Green','Red','Silver','|','blue','Yellow']

var split1 = arr.slice(0, arr.indexOf("|"));
var split2 = arr.slice(arr.indexOf("|")+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is capable of handling more than two delimiters.

```
function splitArr(arr){
  var tmp = arr.join("|").split("||");
  var result = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < tmp.length;i++){  
    result.push(tmp[i].split("|").filter(function(e){
      return e;
    }));
  }
  return result;
}
```

**Working Demo**

```js
        var arr = ['Green','Red','Silver','|','blue','Yellow','|', 'some cool color we do not know about', 'another awesome color'];


        function splitArr(arr){
          var tmp = arr.join("|").split("||");
          var result = [];
          for(var i = 0; i < tmp.length;i++){
            result.push(tmp[i].split("|").filter(function(e){
              return e;
            }));
          }
          return result;
        }

        var newArr = splitArr(arr);
        for(var x = 0; x < newArr.length; x++){
           document.write(newArr[x]);
           document.write("<br/>");
        }
```

Comment: Versatile solution :) have been a fan of your tutorials ^_^

Comment: @TahirHussainMir Thanks!